# Oracle/SQL - Join one table multiple times to the same table

Tags: oracle, join

I'm trying to wrap my brain around a query and hoping you can help.  I have two tables: a customer_table and a product_table that look like this

```
name    sku_num1    sku_num2    sku_num3    sku_num4
----------------------------------------------------    
Bob     A           B           C           D
Frank   E           A
Tom     G
Shelly  G           E
Justin  E           G           A

sku_num     widget_name
-------------------
A           widget_a
B           widget_b
C           widget_c
D           widget_d
```

So what I want to do is return a list of all the customers who have at least 1 product whose SKU appears in the product table.  So with the above information I would receive back the records for

Bob

Frank

Justin

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to *join* one table twice:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE sku_num1 IN (SELECT sku_num
                   FROM product_table)
   OR sku_num2 IN (SELECT sku_num
                   FROM product_table)
   ....
```

The reason why you need multiple conditions that do a full table scan on the `product_table` is your wrong database design. The products a customer bought should not go into multiple columns in the customer table. Instead you should have a third table that is a N:M relation between customer and products.

Comment: +1 for the comment on a broken relational model, which was my first thought.

Comment: I agree it's bad design and not of my doing; thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @dscl: make sure you fix the broken the design before you proceed with the project.

Answer (score 3):

Does something like this not work?

```
select name 
from customer c, products p
where ( c.sku_num1 = p.sku)
or    ( c.sku_num2 = p.sku)
or    ( c.sku_num3 = p.sku)
or    ( c.sku_num4 = p.sku)
```

Comment: You'd get multiple records back per customer if more than one of their products exist in the other table.  Make it `select distinct name ...`.

Comment: You can also do p.sku in (c.sku_num1, c.sku_num2, c.sku_num3, c.sku_num4)

Answer (score 1):

Christopher,
Does this mean that you are just looking for any customers where sku_num1 or sku_num2 or sku_num3 or sku_num4 is not null?

If that's the case, you could do it two different ways.

```
select * from customers 
    where sku_num1 is not null 
    or sku_num2 is not null
    or sku_num3 is not null
    or sku_num4 is not null
```

If you are trying to see if they have ordered something from a specific product list, you could modify this to:

```
select * from customers
    where sku_num1 in (select sku_num from skus)
    or sku_num2 in (select sku_num from skus)
    or sku_num3 in (select sku_num from skus)
    or sku_num4 in (select sku_num from skus)
```

Incidentally, this is why people normally don't structure tables like this.  There should be another join table, for lack of anything better to call it, customer_skus which would tie together customers and skus and just have a customerID and a sku_num.

This would make the query easier to write, read, and maintain.  The query would look something like:

```
select distinct name from customers, customer_skus, skus
    where customers.id = customer_skus.id
    and customer_skus.sku_num = skus.sku_num
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join a table with itself by using an `alias`:

```
select * from mytable a, mytable b where condition
```

Comment: I may have not written the subject line clearly.  I need to join one table 'A' to a different table 'B' multiple times.  Even that I can do... It's the other part of my query I am unsure of how to accomplish.